# MapInfo TEXT in SQLite

Tags: mapinfo, sqlite

I´m trying to add a TAB-file containing text-objects to a SQLIte database. I´ve already added points, lines and polygons, but when I try to add texts I get an error - something about an erroneous action on the server (it´s in Danish, so I´m not quite sure how to translate it).

I´ve heard that I might be missing some additional columns or tables, but I cannot find any informations about it.

Any suggestions/comments are greatly appreciated.

Regards
Kaare

Comment: Which version of MapInfo? And please post the error message.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that your table in SQLite has the necessary columns for storing the text attributes.

These columns have been described in this document: [MI Pro 11.5.2 New Feature Documentation](http://reference.mapinfo.com/software/mapinfo_pro/english/11.5.2/MapInfoProfessionalNewFeatureDocumentation.pdf).
The specific type of columns in not stated, but I guess they are all real/double/float, except Feat_ID which is Integer, Label_Text which is Text and Geometry which is a BLOB.